# Как вывести из БД 6 самых популярных напитков?

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql, данные

Есть таблица `CART_ITEMS`, где `drink_id` - это `id` напитка, а `order_id` - это `id` заказа, в котором он находится, `count` - это количество данного напитка в заказе. Нужно вывести 6 самых популярных напитков из этой таблицы. Как это можно реализовать не пойму... у меня получилось следующим образом:

```sql
select drink_id from cart_items
    where drink_id=(select drink_id from cart_items group by drink_id order by count(6) desc limit 1)
group by drink_id
limit 6
```

Соответственно, это не работает. Выводится всего лишь один самый популярный напиток.

P.S. База от PostgreSQL

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT drink_id, sum(count) as count
FROM cart_items
GROUP BY drink_id
ORDER BY 2 DESC
LIMIT 6
```